# Как понять когда цепочка прототипов завершается?

Tags: javascript, prototype, прототипное-наследование

В первом случае цепочка прототипов длиннее, чем во втором.

```js
function Func() {};
Func.__proto__ == Function.prototype; //true
Func.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype; //true
Func.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype; //false
Func.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype; //Cannot read property '__proto__' of null
```

Во втором случае она короче.

```js
let obj = {};
    obj.__proto__ == Object.prototype; //true
    obj.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype; //false
    obj.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype; //Cannot read property '__proto__' of null
```

Почему? В предпоследней строчке второго примера `obj.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype` непонятно почему выдает `false`. Хотя у `Object.prototype` тоже вроде бы как должно быть св-во `__proto__`. В первом же случае в строке `Func.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype` св-во `__proto__` есть. Почему же здесь его нет? В чем разница?

Comment: _Как понять когда цепочка прототипов завершается?_ - как только значение прототипа `null` - цепочка, очевидно, завершается. Кроме того, _НЕ_ используйте устаревшее свойство `__proto__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В первом случае у вас цепочка прототипов на одно звено больше, потому что в начале там подкласс объекта, а не чистый объект.
2. `__proto__` не всегда ссылается на `Object.prototype`, поэтому в этом нет противоречия:

> В предпоследней строчке второго примера `obj.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype` непонятно почему выдает `false`. Хотя у `Object.prototype` тоже вроде бы как должно быть св-во `__proto__`.

`Object.prototype.__proto__` ссылается не на `Object.prototype`, а на `null`, иначе получилась бы циклическая, бесконечная цепочка прототипов.